Display resource value from another class library for label control text property aspx page
I would like to display in the aspx code behind (not the .cs file) a resource file value (in a separate class library) for a label control text property.
Currently I have class library called Language which will have multiple global resource files as I have multiple web applications that can use the same text. Don't want to create a resource file in each web application that uses the same text, hence a global resource file for both.
I have this working successfully in the code behind (.cs) but prefer to do it via the aspx page:
lblDisplayText.Text = ResourcesGlobal.Common.lblDisplayText;

Code for label control:
<asp:Label ID="lblDisplayText" runat="server" Text="Display Text" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>

But I would like to add to the .aspx file for the label control text property from the global resource file, and have tried many different scenarios, ex. see below, but none have worked.
<asp:Label ID="lblDisplayText" runat="server" Text= "<%# ResourcesGlobal.Common.lblDisplayText; %>" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>

<asp:Label ID="lblDisplayText" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:ResourcesGlobal.Common, lblDisplayText%>" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>


For the class library resource file, the Custom Tool is set to: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator and the Custom Tool Namespace is ResourcesGlobal, and it is Public.
I do reference the library in the code behind:
using ResourcesGlobal;

Does anyone have it working in the UI aspx page?
Thank you.

Did you call DataBind(); at the end of Page_load? Not sure this works for resource files, but for Text='<%# ResourcesGlobal.Common.lblDisplayText %>' it should work.

VDWWD, I did not have databind at the end of page load, thank you very much it works now. Thanks again for your help, much appreciated.
